# My Sites list displays inconsistently

Tags: bug, android-app

When I open the side menu of the app, My Sites shows the sites I am part of. Then I click the edit button and go back. When I open the menu again, all of the meta sites appear too. This persists until I close and reopen the app. Refreshing the page does not remove it. I have not yet changed the items on this list.

Before:

[image: normal sites show]

After:

[image: meta sites appear too]

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LGLS992

  - OS Version: 7.0 (180320959b773)